# URL rewriting with Yii framework

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii

I have a url like

```
www.example.com/food/xyz
```

for which I have written a rule like this in the main.php (config folder)

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '/food/<name:\w+>/' => 'food/index/',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

This means that internally "xyz" will be passed as a parameter to the actionIndex of my FoodController according to the rule

```
class FoodController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($name){
        //some code here
    }

    public function actionItems(){
        //some code here
    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that I have another method in the same class called actionItems and when I use the URL

```
www.example.com/food/items
```

it calls the actionIndex and passes "items" as a parameter

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first rule should be for the items

```
'/food/items'=>'food/items',
'/food/<name:\w+>/' => 'food/index/',
```

Alternatively, I would rather use an alias to split the use of the controller such that all 'food'/<:name>' urls are differentiated from '/food/action' urls for example:

```
'/food/<name:\w+>/' => 'food/index/',
'/foods/<action:\w+>' => 'food/<action>'
```

Comment: Hey Chris.. Thanks! This is the only way to get it working i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just change order:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '/food/<name:\w+>/' => 'food/index/'
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried using the rule in the end but still have the same problem..

Comment: @Rohit this should do what you want. You only have to remove the trailing slashes. If not, then maybe you have to update your question and give a list of examples that show which URLs should go to which action.